# How do electrons flow in BJT common base configuration?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

"When \$V_{CB}\$ increases, the depletion layer between the Base-Collector junction increases. So it requires less Base-Emitter Voltage, \$V_{BE}\$ to forward bias the junction. Therefore, \$I_E\$ increases."

I heard this explanation in a video and I agree with the first two sentences, but I have no idea why in the end \$I_E\$ increases. Wouldn't the electrons be swept to the base and go back to the emitter? If that's the case, then the direction of e- and current become the same?

Comment: Diffusion is the answer. Once in the thin base, the electrons behave like a gas and the collector like a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: No - your 1st sentence is not correct. Any increase in VCB has no significant influence on Ie. (just a small influence due to the Early effect, but this will often be neglected). Any change in Ie (and simultaneously in Ic as well as Ib) is caused by a variation of Vbe. The BJT working principle is the same - for common base, common emitter or common collector.

Comment: @LvW he is probably referring to this https://www.eeeguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Common-Base-Characteristics-of-BJT-1.jpg

Comment: Yes - could be. The graph shows a specific method to visualize the consequences of the Early effect (Vbe reduction for Vcb increase and constant current Ie).

Comment: Or... Ie increase for Vcb increase at constant Veb ;-) (which is what happens when you bring the vacuum cleaner close to the gas release valve)

Comment: What is the Early effect you're mentioning here? @LvW

Comment: The Early effect is described by the sentence you have quoted directly below the figure in your post. For rising VCB less VBE is necessary for constant IE - that means: For constant VBE the current IE (and IC) will increase with rising VCB resp. VCE. This is the reason for the slope of the IC=f(VCE) set of curves.